# Installing header files onto a linux machine without internet access

Tags: c, linux, x11

I'm working with a CentOS 6.0 linux system that has been limited in a whole bunch of ways for security reasons.  It has no internet access, so anything I install on it has to be done manually (for instance, gcc was not included, and to get it on there I had to manually download, copy, and install a bunch of rpms).

Also not included: any of the X11 header files.  I'm not particularly well-versed in linux, and my coding experience is mostly in C#.  I was hoping .h files worked much like .dll files, and I could just copy the X11 header files from a complete Centos 6.0 install onto my restricted one (into */usr/include/X11/*)

This doesn't appear to be the case.  Attempting to compile a C program that includes the Xlib.h header file and calls the command XOpenDisplay returns an error: `test.c:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to 'XOpenDisplay'`

Is there a correct way of installing header files onto a machine like this?

(I am able to compile on my complete Centos install and move the files over to the restricted machine, but this is a lengthy, multi-step process - for security reasons - that makes debugging very tedious.)

Comment: Would be more on topic on Unix&Linux, but most distrib allow to download the full distribution on some DVDs or memory sticks. Once you have that, you can use all the install tools with no need for internet access (except for upgrades).

Comment: As serge notes, you need to create what's called a `local yum mirror`. This could be placed on an external hard drive or intranet. I'm not familiar enough to explain how, but with those keywords a bunch of tutorials that might be useful appear in google.

Comment: Sorry, I was attempting to keep my question concise, not adding any extraneous details that weren't important to the question.  That, and my inexperience with C libraries, made my question unclear.
I was unaware that .h files were separate from the libraries, so my question should have been "How do I install the header files AND libraries onto my machine without an internet connection?"

Answer (score 1):

`test.c:(.text+0x11): undefined reference to 'XOpenDisplay'`

This is a reference to a missing library, not a header file. If the compiler were unable to find the header you would get something like:

`fatal error: x11.h: No such file or directory`

You need to make sure to include the X11 library (link with -lX11).

Comment: Probably, what he really means is the development package, which usually consist on the header files and the library without the version suffix.

Answer (score 1):

The correct way is "to manually download, copy, and install a bunch of rpms". Copying files one by one is not a solution.